# a suitable algorithm to find associations

Tags: associations, data-mining

i have a data set like the following

```
1=> aa,ser,sdf,gg,er,we <br/>
2=> gg,aa,uy,de,or,qq<br/>
3=> aa,er,we,uy<br/>
4=> oo,aa,gg,tr,dw<br/>
5=> iu,gg,re,de,ser<br/>
```

likewise there are about 1000 transactions.
i want to fine what items found more frequently with

> "aa", "aa" and "gg", "oo"

etc...
whenever i name an item, other items that are frequently used with it should be displayed. What type of algorithm/algorithms is suitable to be used in this sort of a situation?

Answer (score 0):

Split it all into one big two-column table:

```
num,wrd
===,===
1,aa
1,er
1,gg
1,sdf
1,ser
1,we
2,aa
2,dd
...
5,re
5,ser
```

From there, it's easier to query out what you want.  For example,

```
select wrd, count(*) from words group by wrd order by count(*) desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

Association rule learning could be a simple and fast option.

There are many options depending on how you want to tune the solution. Check this [survey](http://www.kdd.org/exploration_files/hipp.pdf) on the topic.